# How Can I get the string that present the variable in function argument?

Tags: php

How Can I get the string that present the variable in function argument?

example

```
function dbg($param){
      return "param"; 

 }
 $var="Hello World";
 echo dgb($var);
```

output: `var`

```
 $arr=array();
 echo dgb($arr);
```

output: `arr`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? I am not exactly sure what you are attempting to do.

Upon calling `dgb()`, with any parameter it will simply return the word "param". There is no way to know what the input variable is called when `dbg()` is called.

Comment: `dgb($arr)` → `echo 'arr'`. This has been asked before and it's *not possible* (at least without terrible hacks). I'd be interested in a use case as well.

Comment: @deceze dgb($arr) → echo 'arr' yes,this is want I want in this question,

Comment: I'm saying if that's all you want to do, change `dbg($arr)` to `echo 'arr'`. Yes, this comment is tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is NOT possible to do what you ask reliably.**

The closest you can come up to doing that is to do a `debug_backtrace()` to check which file called the function then tokenize the source of that file to find the reference.

Again, **this will not work reliably**. It will fail if you have multiple calls on one line. Truthfully, it isn't work the trouble. You are writing the code anyway, you know which variable you are passing.

```
function dbg($var) {
  $bt = debug_backtrace();
  $file = $bt[0]['file'];
  $line = $bt[0]['line'];

  $source = file_get_contents($file);

  $tmpTokens = token_get_all($source);
  $tokens = array ();

  foreach ($tmpTokens as $token) {
    if (is_array($token) && $token[0] !== T_INLINE_HTML && $token[0] !== T_WHITESPACE) {
      $tokens[] = $token;
    }
  }

  unset($tmpTokens);

  $countTokens = count($tokens);

  for ($i = 0; $i < $countTokens; $i++) {
    if ($tokens[$i][3] > $line || $i === $countTokens - 1) {
      $x = $i - (($tokens[$i][3] > $line) ? 1 : 0);

      for ($x; $x >= 0; $x--) {
        if ($tokens[$x][0] === T_STRING && $tokens[$x][1] === __FUNCTION__) {
          if ($x !== $countTokens - 1 && $tokens[$x + 1][0] === T_VARIABLE) {
            return $tokens[$x + 1][1];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

printing a variable, you're doing it wrong.
the right ways is like this:

```
function dbg($param){
      return $param; 

 }
 $var="Hello World";
 echo dgb($var);
```

and by the way you're passing an array to a function that only accepts variables. and oh it's a null array all the way worse!

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing that you're trying to make a custom debugger which as a nice touch prints the name of the variable you're debugging. Well, that's not really possible. I'd suggest you look at [`debug_backtrace`](http://www.php.net/debug_backtrace), which allows you to print the file, line number, function name and arguments of the place where you invoked your `dbg` function. Unless you use `dbg` more than once per line that helps you find the information you're looking for, and IMO is a lot more useful anyway.

Alternatively, you can have both the name and value of your variable if you call your function like this:

```
function dbg($var) {
    echo 'name: ' . key($var) . ', value: ' . current($var);
}

$foo = 'bar';
dbg(compact('foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You question doesnt make much sense, you may want to reword it.

It sounds like you want to use the `$param` in the function in which case you can just do something link `echo $param;`